# How to pass blob instead source audio path to convert wave stereo to mono audio in .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, naudio, scnaudioplayer

this is working fine when I am passing source file path but how to pass blob??

1. please help how to pass blob url
2. when i am passing blob url its not working

   ```
   public void Conversion(string sourceFile)
   {
       using (var inputReader = new AudioFileReader(sourceFile))
       {
           try
           {
               // convert our stereo ISampleProvider to mono
               var mono = new StereoToMonoSampleProvider(inputReader)
               {
                   LeftVolume = 1.0f, 
                   RightVolume = 1.0f
               };
               var root = _config.GetValue<string>("DownloadPath");
               if (!Directory.Exists(root))
               {
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
               }
               WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(tempFile, mono);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What's a blob URL / what do you mean by that?

Comment: I need to pass Blob Object instead sourceFile path.

Comment: Daniel Hilgarth, do you have any idea on this? Thanks

Comment: What's a blob object? Please specify exact namespace and type name